# Error sending written text to Wysiwyg by email

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Basically, I write a text and send everything correctly. The problem is when I get this email sent, it comes typed type in HTML. For example ... if I write Thanks! ... and send the email ... while reading the email I sent ... it will be tagged ... I always get something like this: `<p> Thanks! b> Thanks! </ b>`. My objective is to only receive the text ... without the tags.

**View**

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Email", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="Destinatário" placeholder="Para:">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto:">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="summernote" name="Mensagem" class="form-control" style="height: 200px" placeholder="Introduza a Mensagem..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Anexo
                    <input type="file" name="Attachments" multiple="multiple">
                </div>
                <p class="help-block">Max. 32MB</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DashboardV1", "Home")'" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Voltar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" id="sendEmail"></i> Enviar</button>
            </div>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Limpar Tudo</button>
        </div>
    </div>

}

@section Scripts {
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var message = "@ViewBag.Message";
        $(function () {
            if (message != "") {
                alert(message);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#summernote').summernote();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This may help you https://forums.asp.net/t/2112940.aspx?Formatting+HTML+email

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I still can not solve my problem. I did it in a way that I did not use Wysiwyg and everything worked ... my objective is to use this tool because it has more features ... I think the problem really comes from there

Comment: If your MIME type is correct, have you checked that your code isn't escaping/HTMLEncoding on you? This could be causing `<p>` to email as `&lt;p&gt;`

Comment: If you want text without the tags then use a texarea for editing and not a WYSIWYG editor. If you want the email to come in formatted as HTML, then make sure that when you send the email it knows that you are sending HTML. This all comes down to how you are sending the email and less of how you get the text. The MailMessage class has a BodyFormat property that can be used to define the body as HTML. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: put mm.IsBodyHtml = true; and save me !